# NetCDF hourly data to year raster layers (using Python)

Tags: python, netcdf, numpy, xarray

Having a NetCDF with a 'time', 'lat' and 'lon' dimension, where time is hourly during a year and the variable to extract is temperature, how do I calculate mean temperature throughout the year using Python?
(using Python and netcdf4 or xarray or numpy)

Comment: I would use xarray. Add an additional coordinate/dimension that is "year", and then group by year. Please provide some code/example if you want more details. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I would use `xarray.Dataset.resample`. `xarray` is very handy for time series and comes with several temporal dimension handling methods, some of which taken from the comprehensive `pandas`. Check the docs [here](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html). If this does not solve the issue, please add some more context as Rowan asked in the comment.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
da = xr.DataArray(np.linspace(0, 11, num=12), coords=[pd.date_range('15/12/1999',
    periods=12, freq=pd.DateOffset(months=1))], dims='time')
da.resample(time="A").mean()
```

Have a look at different frequency offsets you can input as parameters in the `.resample` method, in the `pandas` documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets).